# Elements of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$ fixed under $\zeta_p \mapsto \zeta_p^g$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I'm reading Harold Edwards’ Galois theory and before going into Galois theory he was discussing about Gauss' works on constructible $n$ gons (so please avoid Galois Theory while answering this question).

Fix a prime $p$ and a primitve root $g$ of $p$. Let $\zeta_p$ be a primitive $p$-th root of unity.

Let $S: \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p) \mapsto \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$ be the automorphism replacing $\zeta_p \mapsto \zeta_p^g$, and let $K_d$ be the set of all elements of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$ invariant under $S^d$. Now he claims the following things:

1. It's easy to see that $K_1 = \mathbb{Q}$ and $K_{p-1} = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$ and if $m | n | p-1$ then $K_m \subset K_n$.
2. It's not hard to see see if $d | D | p-1$ then $K_D$ is a simple algebraic extension of $K_d$
3. Pick a chain $1 = d_0 | d_1 | \cdots | d_z = p-1$ such that every divisor of $p-1$ apperars exactly once. Then consider the tower of fields $K_{d_0} \subset K_{d_1} \subset \cdots K_{d_z}$. Then each element of $K_{d_{i+1}}$ can be expressed as terms of radicals with elements of $K_d$ via methods of Lagrange resolvents.
4. Let $\omega$ be a primitive $p-1$th root of unity. Then if $\sum_{0 \leq i \leq p-2} P_i(\omega) \zeta_p^i = 0$, then $P_i(\omega) = 0$ for all $i$ and this is "hard".

OK, so I don't understand all of them properly and need help understanding them.

1. OK, this is pretty clear.
2. I don't see it why $K_D$ should be a simple algebraic extension of $K_d$ ? The best I can get is this far: Define $\displaystyle \tau_d := \sum_{0 \leq i < \frac{p-1}{d}-1} \zeta_p^{g^{di}}$. Then $\tau_d \in K_d$ but it's not in any $K_m$ for which $m | d$ and $m < d$. But then I'm not sure how $\tau_D$ can be expressed as a root of a polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}(\tau_d)$.
3. Why this should be true ?
4. Isn't this very obvious (I don't get why Gauss found it very hard) ? So we are basically wanting that $[\mathbb{Q}(\omega, \zeta_p): \mathbb{Q}(\omega)] \geq p-1$, but doesn't this follows from if you let $\phi$ to be $p(p-1)$th root of unity then $\mathbb{Q}(\phi) = \mathbb{Q}(\omega, \zeta_p)$, and thus $[\mathbb{Q}(\omega, \zeta_p): \mathbb{Q}(\omega)] = \frac{[\mathbb{Q}(\omega, \zeta_p): \mathbb{Q}]}{[\mathbb{Q}(\omega): \mathbb{Q}]} = \frac{[\mathbb{Q}(\phi): \mathbb{Q}]}{[\mathbb{Q}(\omega): \mathbb{Q}]} = \frac{\phi(p-1)(p-1)}{\phi(p-1)} = p-1$ ?

Comment: By the way, this is not relate to the question; but can someone give some motivation behind norm/trace maps ? They're introduced in a finite field book but I don't see why someone would need them and the book is just random listing (and proving) the properties of them without any motivation/intution.

Comment: $4$ is saying that $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p):\mathbb{Q}] = p-1$ ie. $\frac{x^p-1}{x-1}$ is irreducible, which is not obvious at all. In that case $Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)/\mathbb{Q})$ is cyclic generated by $\zeta_p \mapsto \zeta_p^g$. At first you have no clue the latter is a field morphism so your question is weird. For Galois extensions, the norm, trace and minimal polynomials can be defined in term of the Galois group and their motivation is clear.

Comment: Here’s just one use of the Norm: an algebraic integer is a unit (has an integer as its reciprocal) if and only if its Norm down to a smaller field is a unit there; in particular if and only if its Norm down to $\Bbb Q$ is $\pm1$. Example: $7+5\sqrt2\in\Bbb Z[\sqrt2\,]$ .

Comment: This whole theory of Gaussian periods is now passe (unfortunately). I have presented the same without any Galois stuff in my blog posts [here](https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2009/12/gauss-and-regular-polygons-gaussian-periods.html?m=0) and [here](https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2009/12/gauss-and-regular-polygons-gaussian-periods-contd.html?m=0).

Comment: Trace can be used to characterize separable extensions.